# How can I export and load configurations of Geany?

Tags: geany

I made many changes on build commands and layout on Geany. How can I export and load it?

I want load my configurations on another machine.

Using Geany 1.27-1 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Aren't all user-level settings in the `~/.config/geany` folder?

Comment: i just tried some stuff on geany on raspberry pi.  The changes i made to the build were automatically saved when i clicked exit. and re loaded when i re-started geany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `~/.config/geany` to your new computer on the same location